# Is the source for the original Elite public?

Tags: bbc-micro

Is the source code for the original Elite public? Even after all this time, I'm still flabbergasted at how hard they pushed the BBC Micro, and what they achieved.

A commentary on the disassembly would be interesting, too, but I'd love to see the original. The comments would be fascinating.

Comment: https://6502disassembly.com/a2-elite/ has links to various sources and reconstruction projects, as well as an analysis of the 3D mesh format and other aspects of the game.

Comment: "how hard they pushed the BBC Micro": not only that one, but also the ZX Spectrum for which transforming coordinates from (X,Y) to its video memory addresses needed a bit more work because of the interlaced addresses. I.e. from line 0, the next line was line 8, then line 16, and only at the end of the display, the next address was for line 1.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, the original source code was published by Ian Bell on his web site; it can be found on [the BBC Elite](http://www.elitehomepage.org/bbc/index.htm) page. It has been documented by others; see [pndc’s answer](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/22352/79) for details.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as a simple Google (or other) search would have found: https://www.bbcelite.com/